# C++ WinINET FtpPutFile Error Code 3

Tags: c++, windows, path, wininet

I've got a problem with WinINET's `FtpPutFile()` function.

Here's the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h> 
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")

using namespace std;
void FileSubmit()
{
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: InternetOpen = " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "host", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "name", "pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
        if (hFtpSession == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error: InternetConnect = " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "C:\\Utenti\\Luca\\Desktop\\pop.txt", "pop.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
                cout << "File send" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Error: FtpPutFile = " << GetLastError() << endl;
            InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    }
}

int main()
{
    FileSubmit();
    return 0;

}
```

The program does connect to the Internet, but it seems it can't send the file.  `GetLastError()` returns error code 3.  Maybe because I use wrong path syntax?

Comment: Your path syntax is fine for a string literal. Something else is going on. Are you sure the `C:\Utenti\Luca\Desktop` folder actually exists, and the `pop.txt` file actually exists in it? Error code 3 is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, which usually means a folder cannot be found (vs `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for a missing file). Is your `C:\Users` folder actually named `Utenti`? Have you tried using `Users` instead of `Utenti`? The best way to get the correct path to a user's `Desktop` folder is via `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop)`, don't hard-code it.

Answer (score 0):

`GetLastError` returning 3 means PATH NOT FOUND: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Try to pass a file from program working directory instead.

Comment: "*Try to pass a file from program working directory instead*" - that is not necessary when providing an absolute file path, as the OP's code does.